# Create new object using concatenated strings as object name

Tags: python, oop

I have a simple class that stores information about people attending a conference:

```
class Attendee:
    def __init__(self, fName, lName, email):
        self.fName = fName
        self.lName = lName
        self.email = email
```

I am attempting to create Attendee objects using a combination of two user-inputed strings:

```
#get inputs from user:
fName = input("First name: ")
lName = input("Last name: ")
    .....

newObjectName = fName[0] + lName

newObjectName = Attendee(fName, lName, email)
```

Obviously this will not work - but you get the idea I'm shooting for.
I know in C# you can create a new object by:

```
Attendee newObjectName = new Attendee(fName, lName, email)
```

How would this translate to Python?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you want `newObjectName` to be the name of the variable? That is, if `newObjectName = "bob"` then `bob = Attendee(...)`?

Comment: btw: I don't think the C# code you showed does what you want either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have variable variable names, then you want a different data structure instead.  For example, a dictionary works well:

```
attendees = {}
newObjectName = fName[0] + lName
attendees[newObjectName] = Attendee(fName, lName, email)
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have the code in your question - `newObjectName = Attendee(fName, lName, email)`

Answer (score 0):

> below in the Attendee class you define setters
>   which will set values to your data attributes (variables)
>   whenever an object is created and  the user input the data
>
> and you also define getters which are used to retrieve those data
>   on demand
>
> the last line with **str** will print the object state as a string

```
class Attendee:

    def __init__(self, fName, lName, email):

        self.fName = fName
        self.lName = lName
        self.email = email

    def set_fName(self, fName):
        self.__fName = fName

    def set_lName(self, lName):
        self.__lName = lName

    def set_email(self, email):
        self.__email = email

    def get_fName(self, fName):
        return self.__fName

    def get_lName(self, lName):
        return self.__lName

    def get_email(self, email):
        return self.__email

    def __str__(self):
        return "First name: " + self.__fName + "\nLast name: " + self.__lName + "\nEmail: " + self.__email
```

> below is an example of a main program which asks for user input
>   and creates a class object (of New_attendee class)
>   I added a dictionary which is first created empty ( = {}  )
>   and each entry is stored in the dictionary

```
def main():

    NewAttendee = {}

    again = 'y'

    while again == 'y':

        fName = input("First name: ")
        lName = input("Last name: ")
        email = input("Email: ")

        entry = Attendee(fName,lName, email)

        if fName not in NewAttendee:
            NewAttendee[fName] = entry
            print('The new attendee has been added')
        else:
            print('That name already exists.')

        again = input('Do you want to add a new attendee? \'y\' for yes -->')

main()
```

> Hope that helps!
>   PS: I didnt put the **str** (object state as a string) into action